# select subcells based on a different cell string - matlab

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

Given the following cell array of strings:

```
a(1) = {{'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'}}
a(2) = {{'one', 'two', 'four', 'five'}}
a(3) = {{'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'}}

b = {'one', 'two'}
```

is there a way to check whether *both* strings in `b` are contained in each subcell of `a`?

In my example `a(1)` and `a(2)` would fill this requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>> cellfun(@(x) all(ismember(b, x)), a)

ans =

     1     1     0
```